# curlopt_httpheader equivalent of c#

Tags: c#, php, http, curl

I'm trying to convert a piece of php code to C#. But I can't find any sample of *CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER* equivalent in C#. In fact the code that I try to convert is here:

```
$churi = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apipass:'.$key)); 
$res = curl_exec($churi); 
$obj = json_decode($res);
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: where is your c# code? you just need to add a HTTP header with the apipass as key and $key as value

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HttpClient` you can use the following code for adding custom request headers:

```
var key = "yourkey"
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apipass",key);
```

I hope this can help you